# Selecting next available "bidder number"

Tags: php, mysql, math

In my auction management software, one feature is bidder number management. In which case, you can assign permanent bidder numbers (or buyer numbers) to customers whom you've previously registered on the site.

My problem is, I cannot figure out how to find the minimum available bidder number and assign it, if the user has no given permanent number.

For example..
A given event (auction event) has 4 registered bidders.

```
Bidder #1 => Assigned #21 (has perm num set to #21)
Bidder #2 => Assigned #1 (has no perm num set)
Bidder #3 => Assigned #3 (has perm num set to #3)
Bidder #4 => Assigned #2 (has no perm num set).
```

Also, it must skip a number if someone has that perm num.
So,

```
Bidder #5 => Assigned #5 (for example) because #4 is taken by someone with perm num set to #4
```

My code so far:

```
 if(!empty($_GET['add_bidder'])){
        $cID = $_GET['add_bidder'];
        $eID = $_GET['eventID'];
        $eDI = $_GET['eDI'];
        $sum   = 0;
        $match = 0;

        $sendtext = mysql_query("SELECT c_sms_to_bidders FROM as_companies WHERE c_userID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['s'])."'");
        $send     = mysql_fetch_array($sendtext);

        $getInfo  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM as_users WHERE userID='".$cID."'");
        $gotInfo  = mysql_fetch_array($getInfo);

        $checkPermB   = mysql_query("SELECT c_c_PermB FROM as_company_options WHERE c_c_Company='".$_GET['s']."' AND c_c_User='".$gotInfo['user_token']."' LIMIT 1");
        $checkedPermB = mysql_num_rows($checkPermB);

        if($checkedPermB > 0){
            // User has a perm number.

        } else {
            // User doesn't have a perm number. Let's get all the reserved values..
            $checkPermBNumber   = mysql_query("SELECT c_c_PermB FROM as_company_options WHERE c_c_Company='".$_GET['s']."'");
            $gotPermBNumbers    = mysql_num_rows($checkPermBNumber);

            if($gotPermBNumbers > 0){
                $biddernum = 1;
                if($gotPermBNumbers > 0){
                    while($biddernums = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkPermBNumber)){
                        if($biddernum == $biddernums['c_c_PermB']){
                            $biddernum++;
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    echo "bidder will be given #".$biddernum;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // invalid approach
    }
```

Please ignore the deprecated functions, it was easier to type for example purposes.

So circling back to my question.. what am I doing wrong?
Here's my flowchart:

```
Add Bidder Function Fired =>
Get Info About Given User =>
Check if User Has Perm # =>
=> yes
- get perm bid num, assign, save & wait to add another
=> no
- get next available bidder num (can't be a num that someone has reserved (perm num) and can't be already taken (for given event; bidder numbers are per event), assign next available bidder num, save & wait to add another
```

Comment: What will happen if a permanent number is registered after assigning valid numbers (i.e. the number is invalidated by a future action)? The easiest way is to have disjoint sets for permanent and non-permanent numbers, e.g. with a letter prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on many things. A simple solution would be to have a table with numbers 1,2,3 ... up to say 1 million.

Then you can say:

```
select min(id) from big_table where id not in (select c_c_PermB FROM as_company_options);
```

So select all ids (except those already taken) and take the lowest one.

Keeping a big table like that is of course not the best solution and if you get more than 1 million users you would need to fill the table up with more rows.

If the bidder number you get assigned is the a auto_incremented int for the user table you could just select all user_ids instead of the big table.

Another solution again if this is to slow would be to have a list of 1 million rows again and then remove all registered big numbers and then you would have a list of valid ids. And everytime you assign a registered bidnumber you remove it from the list and then you are good to go. Then when the auction is over you can return all the temporary ids to the big list.

Yet another solution would be to generate the big table on the fly by creating a resultset with 1 to 'highest registered bidding number' + 1 and then using that as the big list. This one would not need any maintanence..

The best solution really depends on how many users you have and how fast it needs to be and how the tables are setup.

The solution above would work but might not be the best one..